# Exiting a form with a button

Tags: java

I have made an interface for a program performing some calculation.
Im stuck at the exit button. Dont know what code to write in the method for the event of the exot button

Should i use setVisible(boolean) property?

Comment: You should provide more details about the implementation, before anybody can try to answer your question. Also, take a look at the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want finish your program you can add.

```
 System.exit(0);
```

Comment: If this worked,  check the answer so this can help others

Answer (score 0):

**dispose()** would be better i think.Because **System.exit(0)** closes all frames while **dispose()** closes the frame which you chose and not all frames.

I dont understand why everybody says that System.exit(0) is the way to go.It is often too general.

Comment: How does the dispose method work.  How do i call it?

Comment: you can call it in the frame for example you put it in your action performed of the frame and just write dispose() then you close the JFrame object you have called it.When you want to close another JFrame you use JFrameObject.dispose() and he closes it